# Spring Batch unable to read csv file

Tags: spring-batch

I am new to Spring Batch and trying to execute this simple batch job, however it look like the csv file is not getting read, i am not getting any error, but the processor is not getting invoked.

The sample-data.csv is already there in my class path/target directory.

```
package hello;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.database.builder.JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.builder.FlatFileItemReaderBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemReader<Person> reader() {
        return new FlatFileItemReaderBuilder<Person>().name("personItemReader")
                .resource(new ClassPathResource("sample-data.csv")).delimited()
                .names(new String[] { "firstName", "lastName" })
                .fieldSetMapper(new BeanWrapperFieldSetMapper<Person>() {
                    {
                        setTargetType(Person.class);
                    }
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
        return new PersonItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<Person>()
                .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<>())
                .sql("INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES (:firstName, :lastName)").dataSource(dataSource)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step1(JdbcBatchItemWriter<Person> writer) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<Person, Person>chunk(10).reader(reader()).processor(processor())
                .writer(writer).build();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no bean of type `Job` in your configuration. Which job are you trying to run?

Comment: @MahmoudBenHassine, creante an answer with the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Mahmoud Ben Hassine After adding the Job it's working fine. Thanks for helping me.